# selenium javascript - how to refer to the test runner window?

Tags: javascript, selenium, hyperlink, click

In my app, in the [firefox] browser javascript console I can do this:

```
elems=document.getElementsByTagName("a")[3]; elems.click();
```

and the 3rd anchor is clicked

How can I do that using the SeleniumIDE ?

I have a Test Case which does:

```
store
javascript{elems=document.getElementsByTagName("a")[3]; elems.click();}
dummy
```

but I just get the somewhat standard invalid javascript error of `[error] Unexpected Exception: fileName -> chrome://selenium-ide/content/selenium-core/scripts/selenium-api.js, lineNumber -> 2535, columnNumber -> 0`

I have also tried

```
javascript{elems=driver.document.getElementsByTagName("a")[3]; elems.click();}
```

and

```
javascript{elems=driver.getElementsByTagName("a")[3]; elems.click();}
```

but neither worked.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
selenium.getEval("var window = this.browserbot.getUserWindow(); var elems = window.document.getElementsByTagName('a')[3]; elems.click();");
```